# How do I recursively list dependencies of a package that need to be installed?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

When doing `apt install`, I would get a list of packages that need to be installed, under the line:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
```

and if there are none, it would continue without prompt. I tried to retrieve this list, but would fail if there are none because the install would just proceed. I want to get this list without installing it.

I tried something like this:

```
apt-cache depends --recurse packagename | grep -v " " | sort -u
```

But it gives a full list including those that are already installed. I want to limit it to those that need to be installed.

I know I can compare the output above with the result of

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

to see which are installed and which are not, but it would involve loops within loops and both lists are quite long. There surely must be a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions. (This is my first time to ask a question here)

**Edit:** I checked out the method using `rdepends` as given in this question:
[Recursive dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468753/recursive-dependencies)

It would have been what I am looking for, except that it results in a different list from what `apt install` gives. It even lists dependencies that are uninstallable (which can't be, given that the package itself installs successfully). What I'm looking for is the list of packages that `apt` would install before the given package. Anyway, I don't understand why the list is different. It should be the same result, right? But since it isn't, then it is not what I am looking for. I would appreciate, however, if someone can explain to me why they give different results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use: `apt -s install ...`

Passing the `-s` option to `apt` causes it to simulate installation but not actually install or modify anything. That shows what you can expect to see from `apt` when you install the package, including which packages if any are pulled in to satisfy its (direct and indirect) dependencies.

For example, to find out what will happen when you install the `apache2` package, you would run:

```bsh
apt -s install apache2
```

That shows you what steps would be taken by `sudo apt install apache2`.

The `-s` option can also be spelled as any of `--simulate`, `--just-print`, `--dry-run`, `--recon`, `--no-act`. So if you see (or write) any of those, they're doing the same thing.

The `-s` option is documented in [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) and not in [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html) (the latter of which doesn't document most features and options), but both `apt-get -s install ...` and `apt -s install ...` are supported.

You can likewise simulate other actions with `-s`, such as the `remove` action.

Unlike with `apt` commands that actually make changes to your system, running `apt -s` as root is optional, so you can omit `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you! The -s solved my issue. You are right that it wasn't in the manpage so I didn't discover it. I wonder though, will this approach work across languages? Since I grepped the word "NEW" then it might work only in English. I ask because this will be part of a script. Or is there a way to parse the output of apt without looking for a specific word?

Comment: Forget my previous comment. I solved that by calling the command as `env LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get -s install packagename`

Comment: After trying many things, including other suggestions here, this seems to be the approach that gives me the most correct answer. Only disadvantage is the need to parse the result. If I can't find a command to give just the list, then this would be the solution.

Comment: Generally scripts should call `apt-get` instead of `apt`, and `apt` tells you about this whenever its stdout is not connected to a terminal.

Comment: Thank you Simon. I'll remember that and always use apt-get in scripts from now on.

Comment: So I finally succeeded in writing a script that will parse the result of `apt-get -s install`. This gives me exactly what I wanted – the list of packages that need to be installed first. But since the approach came from Eliah Kagan, I would like to accept this as the answer. How do I accept an answer? Sorry for my ignorance; this is my first time to ask a question in a forum like this.

Answer (score 6):

It seems `apt -s install` (from [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1286438/567307)) does what you need. Other tools you can consider are `apt-rdepends` and `apt-cache`. However, they list different packages from `apt -s install`, so which to use depends on your needs.

- `apt` may include packages marked "Suggests" and "Recommends", depending on your configuration.
- `apt-rdepends` doesn't exclude packages that are already provided by others. Suppose you have package `xyz-ng` installed, and it provides `xyz`. `apt-rdepends` lists `xyz` because it is a depends that's not installed, but `apt` doesn't need to install `xyz` because it's provided by `xyz-ng`, which is installed.

  - In the above example, `xyz-ng` and `xyz` will conflict. So `xyz` cannot be installed without removing `xyz-ng`.
- `apt-cache` may include unnecessary packages for other reasons, like other architectures (`i386`).

Here is example usage of `apt-rdepends` with output piped to other utilities to clean up the package list:

```
package="whatever"
apt-rdepends \
        --state-follow=NotInstalled --state-show=NotInstalled \
        -f Depends -s Depends "$package" 2> /dev/null | 
    grep Depends\:\ | 
    sed -E 's@\ \(.*\)$@@ ; s@^\s+Depends\:\ @@' |
    sort -u
```

Here is an example using `aptitude` with piped output to clean up the package list:

```
package="whatever"
aptitude -s -y install "$package" |
    sed -E -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' \
           -e 's@(.*\n)+.*NEW\ packages\ will\ be\ installed:\n(.*\n).*RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:(\n.*)+@\2@' \
           -e 's@(\{[a-z]\})?\ @\n@g' |
    sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks again xiota. I will remember this. It so happened that the apt-get solution worked better for my current (specific) need, but depending on my needs, I can see that your solution will be very useful in the future, especially because the apt-get solution depends on user configuration of Suggests and Recommends, and for situations where I don't need to resolve the Provides.

I double checked and noticed that the uninstallable packages given by rdepends are already provided by other packages on my system, hence don't need to be installed anymore.

Comment: Btw, what does `sed -E 's@\ \(.*\)$@@'` do? I get the same result with or without that pipe.

Comment: Some packages show required versions at the end, like `(>= 3.14159)`. That just removes those to get just the pure package name.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with aptitude:

```
$ aptitude \
  --safe-resolver --no-new-installs install <package>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me though. It just told be <packagename> is not currently installed, so it will not be upgraded.

Comment: You may add `--show-resolver-actions` to see what action was taken by the safe-resolver.

Comment: I did `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade --show-resolver-actions --no-new-installs <packagename>` but it still says `<packagename> is not currently installed, so it will not be upgraded.` Anyway, I'm not upgrading a package; I want to check the list of packages that will be installed together with a package.

Comment: This should produce the same result.

Comment: I noticed your edit and so I tried changing aptitude safe-upgrade to aptitude install. This time the message said: Resolving dependencies... No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.

Comment: Filtering is done before the summary. If your package requires a new install, it will be removed. (try something easy cksfv does not have any dep)